# How do I use the locate command within a specified directory?

Tags: linux

I am using the `locate` command on Linux. My current usage of it searches through the entire filesystem. I only want it to search within a specific directory. How can I do this?

Comment: TLDR: Here is a terminal alias to make `locate` search within a specified directory: `alias my_locate="updatedb -U /path/to/yourdir -o /path/to/your_dir_locate.db; locate -d /path/to/dir_locate.db "`  Once the alias is effective, on the terminal type `my_locate *foo*` and you're off to the races.  You can concatenate database updates and locate search by using the colon character to concat databases.  rtfm: https://linux.die.net/man/8/updatedb

Answer (score 15):

Another approach would be to use the pattern matching in `locate`:

```
locate '/some/directory/*filename*'
```

Compare the output of the commands below:

```
$ locate tmpfile
/usr/lib64/perl5/auto/POSIX/tmpfile.al
/usr/share/man/fr/man3/tmpfile.3.gz
/usr/share/man/ja/man3/tmpfile.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/tmpfile.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3p/tmpfile.3p.gz
$
$ locate '/usr/lib64/*tmpfile*'
/usr/lib64/perl5/auto/POSIX/tmpfile.al
$
```

`locate /usr/lib*tmpfile*` gives the same result.

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer. Note that if you include the wildcard, the boundaries become fixed. That is in the above example, `$ locate '/usr/lib64/*tmpfile'` will return no results.

Comment: If you want more control than simple wildcards can offer, you can always pipe the results of `locate` through `grep`.

Answer (score 6):

Create slocate database for your specific directory with:

```
updatedb -U /path/to/directory
```

and search with:

```
locate <search_string>
```

---

**UPDATE**

This works fine on my Gentoo system but CentOS doesn't include `-U` option. So, you can try below instead:

Build the database with:

```
# updatedb -U /path/to/dir -o dir_locate.db
```

and search:

```
# locate -d dir_locate.db <search_string>
```

Comment: "locate -U" throws an invalid option error... Guessing you meant "updatedb -U"?  Also good to note this requires an mlocate.db rebuild (updatedb) if you ever want to search another directory.

Comment: Oh, on my Gentoo it works fine but CentOS doesn't include this option.

Comment: Down vote? Could you please leave a comment?

Comment: If you have error like: `updatedb: can not change group of file 'db.db.kHhzFz' to 'mlocate': Operation not permitted`, check [how to use updatedb command as an ordinary user on linux](http://superuser.com/questions/467181/how-to-use-updatedb-command-as-an-ordinary-user-on-linux).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer I can think of is

```
locate search_term | grep "/specified/directory"
```

The better solution might be to use "find" and its path options...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is as in the following example:

```
updatedb -o ~/tmp.db -l0 -U $PWD
locate   -d ~/tmp.db "foo"
```

Change `$PWD` into your specific directory.

The example above will create your local database only for the specific directory.